# They acted out how they met

Tags: phrase-meaning

According to a dictionary 'act out' means to show the events that happened in a situation by doing them again or by doing the same things as the people involved.

I was talking about a wedding and said:

*Both the bride and the groom danced together. They also **acted out how they met and fell in love** and finally ended up marrying each other.*

Was my sentence correct? They were showing us how they met by acting. It was like a stage show.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence is correct. I would try to avoid using "and" so many times, though, and the "Both" is perhaps unnecessary as you have a "together".

I would say: "The bride and the groom danced together. They also acted out how they met, fell in love, and finally ended up marrying each other."